# Generate list of semantically related words

Tags: language, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for a method of generating lists of words which belong to the same class of "things" or concepts provided. Google (Labs I think) used to have an app where you could type words, e.g.:

- lemon
- Bannana
- starfruit

And it would generate more fruit based on this initial list.

Apparently in linguistics, "fruit" is referred to here as a [hypernym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy) whose semantic field includes hyponymns such as apple, orange etc. I'd like to find the co-hyponyms (other fruits) which belong to hypernyms I didn't think of (i.e.: Yellow colored foods) but can be inferred from the list of words.

This might be a difficult problem requiring specific AI, but it might also be achieved with lexical databases like WordNet, auto-complete suggestions of Google search terms, computer vision classification, natural language libraries, or structured vocabularies/ontologies, etc.

Can anyone suggest an app that does this?